# How to detect if a site cannot be embedded via iframe?

Tags: javascript, http, frames

I'm trying to embed some random sites in an iframe. I'm getting this error:

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

I'm willing to respect their wishes and not embed it, but I'd like to be able to detect that this is set, so that I can try and reload another page. Is there an easy to way to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either using CURL server side or using AJAX request. Either way, the idea is that you make a request to the website in question and simply check whether the response contains `X-Frame-Options`.

Comment: wouldn't the ajax request fail cause the site is not on the same domain?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the error-response will still contain the refraining header.