# Detect X-Frame-Options Clientside

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe that houses third-party content and every so often I'll get a site that has `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN|DENY` set. Is it possible to detect this clientside?

Comment: This link may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378896/how-to-detect-if-a-site-cannot-be-embedded-via-iframe